# Sort values in stacked bar chart ( by number of values not alphabetically)

Tags: pandas, stacked-chart

I want to create stacked bar chart which shows how number of leads by channels changed over a time.

```
         ID DATE_CREATE SOURCE_ID
320086  344424  2021-12 Facebook
320087  344425  2021-12 Facebook
320088  344426  2021-12 Whatsapp
320089  344427  2021-12 Whatsapp
320090  344428  2021-12 Whatsapp
320091  344429  2021-12 Whatsapp
320092  344430  2021-12 Whatsapp
320093  344431  2021-12 Whatsapp
320094  344432  2021-12 Whatsapp
320095  344433  2021-12 Whatsapp
320096  344434  2021-12 AXCAPITAL
320097  344435  2021-12 Whatsapp
320098  344436  2021-12 Whatsapp
320099  344437  2021-12 Facebook
320100  344438  2021-12 Emirates.Estate
```

Here is a piece of my Dataset

My code:

```
leads['DATE_CREATE']=pd.to_datetime(leads['DATE_CREATE'])
leads['DATE_CREATE']=leads['DATE_CREATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
last_leads=leads[leads['DATE_CREATE']>='2020-01']
top_leads=last_leads[(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='Facebook')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='AXCAPITAL')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='Website Visitor')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='TELESALES')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='Instagram')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='AXCAPITAL UKRAIN')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='Company Referral')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='LISTINGS PORTAL')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='Whatsapp')| 
(last_leads['SOURCE_ID']=='BAYUT C') ]
grouped=top_leads.groupby(['DATE_CREATE', 'SOURCE_ID']).size().unstack(level=-1).plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10) )
```

My chart:

[image: My Chart]

I want it to order 'SOURCE_ID' by the number of leads, but here it is given alphabetically. Can you help, please?

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example. This means minimal but self-sufficient code which once copied and executed would give us a representative graph. (Don't forget to include data)

Comment: Edited, can you check now please

Comment: An image is not reproducible date ;) you need to provide a dataframe constructor in your code

Comment: so, how is it now?

Comment: number of leads are for each DataFrame different, do you need sort labels by values in some `DATE_CREATE` like in `2021-12` ? Or need sorting by sum of values?

Answer (score 0):

If need sorting by sum of `SOURCE_ID` values use:

```
leads['DATE_CREATE']=pd.to_datetime(leads['DATE_CREATE']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

last_leads=leads[leads['DATE_CREATE']>='2020-01']

cats = ['Facebook','AXCAPITAL','Website Visitor','TELESALES',
        'Instagram','AXCAPITAL UKRAIN','Company Referral','LISTINGS PORTAL',
        'Whatsapp','BAYUT C']
#simplier alternative solution for filtering and crosstab
top_leads=last_leads[last_leads['SOURCE_ID'].isin(cats)]

grouped = pd.crosstab(top_leads['DATE_CREATE'], top_leads['SOURCE_ID'])
grouped = grouped.iloc[:, np.argsort(-grouped.sum())]

grouped.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10) )
```